# Userform change the textbox colour based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I am trying to change the colour of the textbox in a userform based on the value in the textbox compared to the cell value in C10, i.e if textbox value is 9 and cell value is 10 the colour is green

the below code make the textbox the same colour regardless of values entered

```
Private Sub TextBox16_Change()
If ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value > TextBox16.Value Then
    Me.TextBox16.ForeColor = &H8000000D
    Me.TextBox16.BackColor = &HFF&
Else
    Me.TextBox16.ForeColor = &HFF&
    Me.TextBox16.BackColor = &H8000000D
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: That's a great start - what's the question?

Comment: where am I going wrong with the code to make the textbox green if the textbox value is less than or equal to the cell value C10 and red if textbox value is greater than cell value C10

Comment: Textbox returns text so try converting to long or double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
`If ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value > CLng(TextBox16.Value) Then`

But you'll need to add some error handling because when textbox gets empty, or some other value than number you'll end up with 'type mismath' error.

Comment: Think that's the right lines but perhaps double in case not a whole number?

Comment: Perfect Thank you very much